# Presenting two view controller, dismissing correct view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a password viewcontroller which is presented always when app is activated.

I have another viewcontroller which is presented on click of a button. In this there is a process to be shown and once it is complete dissmiss itself.

The scenario is:

1) Present this view contoller, process starts.

2) Before this process is finished, press home button.

3) Now open app again.

4) Password viewcontroller is presented, as it is mandatory.

5) At this time that process started in step 1 completes. Dismiss method is called. But Password view controller is dismissed instead of this process VC.

How can I dismiss particular presented VC?

```
**Edit:**
```

I tried a different way for this. When I present passcodeVC from appdelegate, I create a new navigation and set it to rootViewController. Earlier nav is stored in a reference. Here I succeded in keeping passcode view. Passcode view is not dismissed now.

When user enters passcode then I change rootviewcontroller again to old. I thought this will work. But, it does not. MailVc is dismissed. And when I try to present mailVC again, it says `this is already presented.`

Seems like, since I change rootVC, and then dissmissVC is called when it is not present in view. 
Can some one explain me this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try delegate pattern? Also for doing process dont present as controller, or if you are doing that just save the progress when application is entering into background and dismiss the progress controller

Comment: Yes. I solved the problem using delegate. But I wanted to know the edited question. Why this happened. When view is not in window root and dismiss is called. View is dismissed. But later when I try to present again, It says already presenting. Even I created new instance of that class to present.

Comment: As you  root controller the rootVC has presented the view, so when you set it again before changing the rootVC just dismiss the progress VC or as I told you when application is entering into background.

Answer (score 0):

Before dismissing the current view controller, you can test its type. If it is `kindOfClass` (YourPasswordViewController), don't dismiss it. Otherwise, dismiss away.

From you UIViewController that does the calculation and dismisses the current `UIViewController`, do the following.

Get instance to your `UINavigationController`. Get `viewControllers` property. It's an `NSArray`. Access the last `UIViewController` and test if it's object of PasswordUIViewController. If it is, then don't dismiss it.

Comment: Ok. But how to find this view controller. navCtrl has viewcontrollers property which gives pushed views. How to get presented view.

Comment: @Durgaprasad updatd my answer. Let me know if you have any confusion

Comment: When I access nav.viewcontrollers I get array of homeVc and mailVc. I do not get presented viewcontroller.  have two presented vc i.e. mailVc and passcodeVC.

Comment: You havent pushed controller so you will not get the present controller status? its viewController method